# Alternative RAID Controller to an Adaptec 3805

Tags: hardware-raid, raid-controller

Our server room has a HP DL180 G5 with 8 disks (RAID 6) and a flakey Adaptec 3805 RAID controller. I want to replace this controller as I don't trust it (See my first post for more details if you want background info.)

Can anyone please recommend an alternative replacement for the Adaptec 3805. Will a HP Smart Array P410/256 work in the DL180 G5 (The HP site says it's ok for a DL180 G6 but doesn't say if it will be ok in a G5.)

Comment: You might just want to make sure that the firmware on the Adaptec controller is up-to-date first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes all of the Pxxx-series controllers will work just fine in a G5.

Answer (score 0):

6805Q ;)

Especially if you plan to expand. I run a 5805 with a 24 disc system and am in the process of planning an expansion to the 6805q with a 72 disc chassis.

The SSD Read/Write cache possibility is terrific.

Answer (score 0):

For that machine, I'd recommend a used HP Smart Array P400 controller, as it has the same SAS SFF-8484 internal cabling and is age-appropriate to the G5 server.

There's no compatibility with your existing array, so you will have to reformat the disks.